# Rails devise: How to sign in a different account without sign out previous one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
Sign in to a  account (A), Close the tab, and go back to the  website
Sign in to a different  account (B)

Expected result: You are now signed in to account B
Actual result: You are still signed in to account A
```

This appears to be because the session is not being cleared before running authentication methods.
The Warden authentication method is idempotent - it looks to the session first and if there's an authenticated account there, it doesn't check the incoming credentials.
Therefore when we try to authenticate using this method but an existing account is logged in, it just uses the existing account no matter whether the incoming credentials are valid or not.
So our current solution would be to destroy the session in the new method before calling warden.authenticate!.

Here is my session_controller

```
    def create
      session.destroy

      warden.authenticate!(scope: :account)
      super do |resource|
        ......
      end
      ...
    end
```

but when I was writing the test case,  it always hard to run step by step into the second post. it always failed in the middle of the second post action

```
      it 'changes to other account if you try to sign in without signing out' do
        post :create, params
        byebug
        post :create, new_params
        expect(subject.current_account).to eq new_account
      end
```

Comment: This looks like you're testing it wrong. In request specs you're just send "raw" requests and while you can override the session by passing the session keyword argument it's not really optimal compared to an feature spec - capybara is actually made to simulate a browser and you can simulate different browsers by using Capybara::Session.

Comment: Also note that devise does not let you have multiple signed in users in a single warden scope as the claim is just stored in the session as an integer/string and not an array of strings.the same browser may appear to have multiple users signed in but that's just because the different tabs may have different session storage cookies.

Comment: And remember that its near impossible to actually sign a user out across all browsers unless you replace ActionDispatch::CookieStore with another session storage mechanizm like ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

use the warden test helpers login_as(user) and logout, so the test would be something like

```
login_as(User.first)
post :create, params
assert page.success
logout
post :create, new_params
assert page.404_access_denied
```

use a as_user() helper which wraps up those calls

https://github.com/code-and-effect/effective_test_bot/blob/master/test/support/effective_test_bot_login_helper.rb

(these are all minitest examples)
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-(and-RSpec)

So here are two examples which can run successfully in my code:

```
    it 'changes to other account if you try to sign in without signing out' do
      post '/accounts/sign_in', { account: { email: account.email, password: account.password } }, json_headers
      post '/accounts/sign_in', { account: { email: other_account.email, password: other_account.password } },
           json_headers

      expect(response.status).to eq(201)
      expect(response_body).to include('id' => other_account.id)
    end
```

```
   it 'causes the borrower to be redirected to its sign out path' do
      login_as account, scope: :account
      delete '/accounts/sign_out', { account: { email: account.email, password: account.password } }

      expect(response).to redirect_to(account.sign_out_url)
    end
```